# java pattern regex accepting string or string followed by digit

Tags: java, regex

Having trouble with this piece of code. It is suppose to accept the following inputs, U,R,E,X 

OR 

 +,-,*,/ followed by a space and digit

 it has to be looped until user Enters E to evaluate whatever is in the stack or queue

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
   Scanner input = new Scanner( System.in );//scanner
   System.out.println("COMP10152 - Lab#5 - Calculator using Queues and Stacks ... by _______________ \n");
   System.out.println("Enter tokens. Legal tokens are integers, +, -, *, /, U[ndo], R[edo], E[valuate] and [e]X[it] ");
   while (!input.hasNext("[UREXurex]?[+-*/]{1}[s][0-9][1]")) {
System.out.println("Invalid Entry - Please enter operation (operator(+,-,*,/) value) or U,R,E,X");
input.next();
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
([urexUREX]+|[\\+\\-\\*\\/]\s+\d)
```

This should work.

**Edit**:

```
^([urexUREX]+|[\\+\\-\\*\\/]\s[^\s]*\d+)$
```

This satisfies all the stated conditions.

Comment: I dont want u,r,e,x followed by a number so would it be \b[urexUREX]?.[+-*/].*[0-9]\b ?

Comment: So basically you want UREX followed by +-*/ followed by any digit, right?

Comment: no sorry what i want is if user inputs U,R,E or X than it does whatever but If the user inputs +,-,* or /, it must be followed by a space and a digit. IE. user enter E, it does whatever its suppose to do but if a user types in + it has to have a space and a digit following

Comment: Enter tokens. Legal tokens are integers, +, -, *, /, U[ndo], R[edo], E[valuate] and [e]X[it] 
+ 2
Invalid Entry - Please enter operation (operator(+,-,*,/) value) or U,R,E,X
Invalid Entry - Please enter operation (operator(+,-,*,/) value) or U,R,E,X

Comment: So I've checked it myself and posted the final edit. (:

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
([UREXurex]+|[\\+\\-\\/\\*]+\\s\\d+)
```

---

Edit:

Check this one:

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner( System.in );//scanner
           System.out.println("COMP10152 - Lab#5 - Calculator using Queues and Stacks ... by _______________ \n");
           System.out.println("Enter tokens. Legal tokens are integers, +, -, *, /, U[ndo], R[edo], E[valuate] and [e]X[it] ");
          String s;
           while (input.hasNextLine()) // Check if there is line to read
           {
               s=input.nextLine(); // read the whole line and save it.
               if(s.matches("([UREXurex]+|[\\+\\-\\/\\*]+\\s\\d+)") ) // true if the regex matches
               {
                   System.out.println("done");
               }
               else
               {
                      System.out.println("Invalid Entry - Please enter operation (operator(+,-,*,/) value) or U,R,E,X");
               }

    }
```

I think the problem is with `hasNext()`. Usually it checks till it encounters a space. So when you provide `+ 2` it checks till `+`. But I don't know if this behaviour is same when you provide regex.

I tried to read the line using `nextLine()` instead of `next()` to prevent the above problem. To check for the regex use `matches()`.

Comment: UREX part works but second half doesnt. I enter + 2 and my error message comes up

Answer (score 0):

Since you only have 2 cases, I would break it up into 2 regex and use the Java regex library:

```
import java.util.regex.*;
...
String regex1="[UREXurex]";
String regex2="[\\+\\-\\*\\/] \\d";
Pattern p1 = Pattern.compile(regex1);
Pattern p2 = Pattern.compile(regex2);
String tokens = "";
tokens = input.nextLine();
```

Now you can match on each of the 2 cases:

```
  if(p1.matcher(tokens).matches()) {
    // process "u, r, e, x" 
  ...
  if(p2.matcher(tokens).matches()) {
    // process operator digit 
  ...
  else {
    // invalid input
```